# Writing Zip Files to GAE Blobstore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, zip, blobstore

I'm using the Java API for reading and writing to the Google App Engine Blobstore.

I need to zip files directly into the Blobstore, meaning I have `String` objects which I want to be stored in the Blobstore when zipped.

My problem is that standard zipping methods are using `OutputStream` to write, while it seems that GAE doesn't provide one for writing to the Blobstore.

Is there a way to combine those APIs, or are there different APIs I can use (I haven't found such)?

Answer (score 6):

If I am not wrong, you can try to use the [Blobstore low level API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore). It offers a Java `Channel` (`FileWriteChannel`), so you could probably convert it to an `OutputStream`:

```
Channels.newOutputStream(channel)
```

And use that output stream with the java.util.zip.* classes you are currently using ([here](http://denis-tsyplakov.livejournal.com/34667.html) you have a related example that uses Java NIO to zip something to a `Channel`/`OutputStream`)

I have not tried it.

Comment: I see you are a new user here. You should mark the answer as accepted it that solved your problem. That helps other people, too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example to write content file and zip it and store it into blobstore:

```
AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile("application/zip","fileName.zip");

try {

     FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, lock);

     //convert as outputstream
    OutputStream blobOutputStream = Channels.newOutputStream(writeChannel);

    ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(blobOutputStream);                    

     zip.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("fileNameTozip.txt"));

     //read the content from your file or any context you want to get
     final byte data[] = IOUtils.toByteArray(file1InputStream);                    

     //write byte data[] to zip
      zip.write(bytes);

     zip.closeEntry();                    
     zip.close();

     // Now finalize
     writeChannel.closeFinally();
 } catch (IOException e) {
     throw new RuntimeException(" Writing file into blobStore", e);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is using BlobStore api, but currently the recommended way is to use App Engine GCS client.

Here is what I use to zip multiple files in GCS :

```
public static void zipFiles(final GcsFilename targetZipFile,
                            Collection<GcsFilename> filesToZip) throws IOException {

    final GcsFileOptions options = new GcsFileOptions.Builder()
            .mimeType(MediaType.ZIP.toString()).build();
    try (GcsOutputChannel outputChannel = gcsService.createOrReplace(targetZipFile, options);
         OutputStream out = Channels.newOutputStream(outputChannel);
         ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(out)) {

        for (GcsFilename file : filesToZip) {
            try (GcsInputChannel readChannel = gcsService.openPrefetchingReadChannel(file, 0, MB);
                 InputStream is = Channels.newInputStream(readChannel)) {
                final GcsFileMetadata meta = gcsService.getMetadata(file);
                if (meta == null) {
                    log.warn("{} NOT FOUND. Skipping.", file.toString());
                    continue;
                }
                final ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(file.getObjectName());
                zip.putNextEntry(entry);

                ByteStreams.copy(is, zip);
                zip.closeEntry();
            }
            zip.flush();
        }

    }
```