# Create a large Zip file on Gae (in blobstore)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, zip, blobstore, task-queue

I am trying to generate a report in XML format on the google app engine (java version). I process several objects stored in the datastore and create XML chunks representing said objects which are sent through streams to the blobstore. The problem is that the generated xml can be huge so I'd like to shrink it using zip compression. The Xml data could then be reduced to less than a tenth of the original size. The zip file is simple as it only contains one file with the original xml data.

I use tasks sent to the taskqueue to process the data and the recipe described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14315315/1015437) to create the zip file and put it in the blobstore. It all works fine if the data can be completely processed within one task execution (cca 10 minutes). I do not know how (or if it is possible) to somehow store the state of the zip stream and continue to write the zip file where the previous task left off.

Answer (score 1):

Run your task on a backend. Then you won't be restricted to a deadline of 10 minutes. Your task may also run more quickly (if CPU was your bottleneck).

Comment: If I am not mistaken there is no free quota for backends and I'd have to pay for the backend instance(s) immediately. I'd rather use up my daily free quota with tasks so I do not see this as a solution unless I am mistaken about the paying issue.